# refactor a struct with internal static properties

Tags: c#, struct, properties, static

I am confronted with a fairly big number of classes by a former employee. While inspecting what the code does I came across a `struct` with `internal static` properties.

The struct is used fairly often. Most properties have only a `get` but some do have a `set` and `get`. The struct is around ~200 lines long with nested internal structs in it.

I can't wrap my head around this struct and what the person wanted to achieve with it.

It's not tested and there is no documentation which leaves me wondering why the person decided to implement something like this.

The struct holds mostly settings and paths that are used throughout the program.

Before I refactor this code and call it an "early masterpiece" of the developer who did that, I want to check if not maybe I am mistaken and its a fairly reasonable idea to use something like this in a very rare occasion.

**My questions are:
Why should someone use a struct with public static properties and how would someone get rid of it (maybe a well known refactoring or something like that), since its used throughout the code (~800 references counted by Visual Studio)**

*BTW:
its not placed in any namespace whatsoever*

```
internal struct ConfigurationPaths
{
    private static string _pathConfig;
    private static string _pathConfigUI;
    private static string _pathConfigUI_Default;
    private static string _pathConfig_DataToView;
    //... removed the following lines due to readability in the question

    internal static string AppPath
    {
        get
        {
            Module[] mod = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules();
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(mod[0].FullyQualifiedName);
        }
    }

    internal static string FilePath
    {
        set { _pathConfig = value; }
        get { return _pathConfig; }
    }

    internal static string UserInterface
    {
        set { _pathConfigUI = value; }
        get { return _pathConfigUI; }
    }

    internal static string UserInterface_Default
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pathConfigUI_Default == null)
            {
                String appPath = AppPath.AppendPathSeperatorIfNeeded();
                _pathConfigUI_Default = String.Format("{0}files{1}config{1}ui{1}default.ux", appPath, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

            }
            return _pathConfigUI_Default;
        }
    }

    internal static string UserInterface_GridView
    {
        set { _pathConfig_DataToView = value; }
        get { return _pathConfig_DataToView; }
    }
    //... removed the following lines due to readability in the question
}
```

Comment: A candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) IMO.

Comment: To me, this looks like an implementation of some kind of helper class. The fact that they are static and returning settings suggests this. The internal scope is possibly because they only wanted it accessing from the 1 assembly.

Comment: The bigger question for me is: Why is this a struct in the first place? Use of `struct` is not a casual design decision, and here it appears to have been misapplied.

Comment: Yeah, agree with @spender - this looks like it is really a `static class`, and any use of `struct` is misleading and is only adding confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the intent was for configuration. If that's the case a static class would be more useful

```
internal static class Configuration { ... }
```

A `struct` doing this provides no value and is not idiomatic. As to why they did it...probably just not the greatest developer. I would place the config class in the root namespace of the project though they probably put it in no namespace to avoid some `using` declarations throughout the code base.

If the global/static nature bothers you I'd suggest converting the whole thing to instance properties and pass that to the things that need it. Doing this, it becomes more like a configuration service -- perhaps removing the setters altogether and internalizing the code that was doing the setting. It would certainly be more OO that way.

That would also lend itself to dependency injection and testability, especially if you slap an interface over it.

Comment: Mutable `struct`s are evil. Converting to instance properties should follow converting to a `class`.

Comment: I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

Static classes are a rather common mistake for Configuration Data, DatabaseAccess and similar cases. It is so common, even Microsoft itself did it [at least once](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

But as I said: It is a mistake. If you ever have to replace the code due to some backend changes - much less getting a mutable backend - it will come back to bite you. A class/struct that needs instantiation, with a instance assigned to a static field is the closest I ever got. That way at least you can change out the instance at runtime.

As for why he used a struct rather then a class: As no instantiation is needed, the difference between both types is largely irrelevant. It could be he was a native C++ programmer. For them the only difference between struct and class is if the default accessor is public or private.